# WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for repositories from Spring Data

Tags: java, spring-data, wildfly, cdi, entitymanager

My current work is to migrate my Java EE application from Jboss 7 server to Wildfly 10. I have a problem with integrate CDI and Spring-Data. I use this same configuration that worked on Jboss 7. When im trying deploy my application to Wildfly server I receive errors related to inject spring data repositories into some CDI and EJB beans.

Errors look like this:

```
 org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type StudentExtTrainingRepository with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private pl.mynetwork.mylearning.logic.historyTraining.HistoryTrainingService.studentExtTrainingRepository
  at pl.mynetwork.mylearning.logic.historyTraining.HistoryTrainingService.studentExtTrainingRepository(HistoryTrainingService.java:0)

    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:359)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:281)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:134)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:155)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:518)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:68)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:66)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:56)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
```

I configured my application according to spring data configuration guide, that i found here https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpd.misc.cdi-integration but on wildfly it doesnt work.

I have producer class for Entity Manager like this

```
@Dependent
public class SpringDataConfigurationProducer {  


  @Produces
  @ApplicationScoped
  public EntityManagerFactory createEntityManagerFactory() {
    return Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("base-pu");
  }

  @Produces
  @RequestScoped
  public EntityManager createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
  } 
}
```

Of course i have files beans.xml in my projects under META-INF directory.

Repository, that im trying inject looks like this:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
@Dependent
public interface StudentExtTrainingRepository extends JpaRepository<StudentExtTraining, Long> {
}
```

Service where i want to inject Repository looks :

```
@Service
public class HistoryTrainingService {

  @Inject
  private StudentExtTrainingRepository studentExtTrainingRepository;
}
```

I have separate project for spring data repositories and separate for Services/EJBs. Both are packed to one EAR. Does anyone have any sugestions what wrong is ? I spent many hours with this problem and i can`t find solution.

Comment: Drop Spring completely and use Apache Deltaspike instead. No troubles with that. There are internal bridges that integrate Spring Data and CDI. And they are not really written very well. Do not mix Java EE and Spring is my advice. Spring is proprietary and does not work well with it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this class too.

```
class CdiConfig {    
  @Produces
  @RequestScoped
  @PersistenceContext
  public EntityManager entityManager;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing SpringDataConfigurationProducer and only with CdiConfig? for me it worked in weblogic. Also add @PersistenceContext(unitName = "base-pu") here.

Comment: Is doesnt work still. When i did it i received error
`Error injecting persistence unit into CDI managed bean. Can't find a persistence unit named 'base-pu' in deployment mylearning-scheduler.ear for injection point javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory pl.mynetwork.mylearning.springdata.config.CdiConfig.customerDatabasePersistenceUnit`

Comment: That means, your primary problem for unsatisfied dependency resolved. Now comes another which is about your directory structure. You need to create another jar containing persistence.xml and put that jar inside lib directory. That way it will be shared among the module jars, otherwise it is not visible for jars except the jar containing it.

Comment: domain.jar and jdbc.jar should be inside services.ear, not in lib directory. only the new jar with persistence.xml should be in lib along with other dependency library jars.

Comment: one more thing, to create the persistence jar, persistence.xml should be inside META-INF

Comment: i worked around problem with inject persistence unit into CDI bean. But still, event with producer field like you recommended, i have a problem with injecting repositories, so still i am in this same place....

Answer (score 0):

I wonder, maybe problem is with my project structure?

I have persistence.xml file inside jar, that is added to lib directory within services.ear.
I have another ear - scheduler.ear, that has dependency to services.ear in manifest file. 
Does know anyone, should it work in this configuration ?

It looks like this:

```
--services.ear
              ----lib
                     -----domain.jar
                                   ---persistence.xml
                     -----jdbc.jar 
--scheduler.ear
              ----META-INF
                          ----Manifest.mf
```

Inside Manifest file i have line like this:

Dependencies: deployment.mylearning-services-app.ear

Repositories classes, that i can`t inject are inside jdbc.jar.
Deployment is failed on stage deploying scheduler.ear